# JPA2: how to get count between the two ids

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa-2.0

I have Group table which has columns id, name, timestamp. When there is an update of a group, the timestamp is also updated with current.

I am trying to display the count of groups between two ids using a query.

```
 Select Count(g) from Area.Group g where g.id between ?2 and ?3 order by g.timestamp desc
```

The group table has:

```
        id  name    timestamp
        ==  ====    ======================
        271 News    20170912123733302+0000
        272 Groups  20170831121326734+0000
        273 A law   20170906075010972+0000
        274 Test    20170906135003580+0000
        275 Topic   20170906135139874+0000
        276 Too     20170906135315684+0000
        299 Q       20170911110126882+0000
        300 R       20170911110254626+0000
        301 S       20170911113756910+0000
        302 T       20170911130306836+0000
        303 Test    20170911135557812+0000
        304 Tf      20170911135724170+0000
        305 Ifti    20170911140254131+0000
        306 Ghdu    20170911140358890+0000
        307 Gifts   20170911140751073+0000
        308 It      20170911140752881+0000
        309 E       20170912123713640+0000
        310 Ye      20170911162441817+0000
        311 Asd     20170912052132275+0000
```

by using the two ids, I am trying to get the count (the order is in decreasing order of timestamp). For example, ids between 271 and 303. The count that I am looking here is 10.

```
        id  name    timestamp
        ==  ====    ======================
        271 News    20170912123733302+0000
        309 E       20170912123713640+0000
        311 Asd     20170912052132275+0000
        310 Ye      20170911162441817+0000
        308 It E    20170911140752881+0000
        307 Gifs    20170911140751073+0000
        306 Ghdu    20170911140358890+0000
        305 Ifti    20170911140254131+0000
        304 Tf      20170911135724170+0000
        303 Test    20170911135557812+0000
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: what's your question  ?   you have error ?  wrong result?

Comment: The count that I am receiving is 11 which is incorrect. If we look the descending order of timestamp, the count which I am expecting is 10.

Answer (score 1):

Group is a reserved  word you should avoid naming table with these words but if you need  then  the word should be inside backtics

```
Select Count(*) from `Group` g where g.id between ?2 and ?3 order by g.timestamp desc
```

Once you have corrected  the `GROUP` column name remain the aspect related  the use of `between`

NB: the ORDER BY  work  on the result of the select   don't perform a filter ..   so you must count the number of rows between  271 and 303  on the original  raw table data ..
Using the `where  ... between` on  column `g.id` mean that the sequence of the values is evaluated  on g.id  column indipendently of the order by you choose . 
In fact in your sample looking to the values ordered  by g.id  you have 11 rows

Comment: Understood, that's the query from the code. Any way I updated the query in my question.

Comment: Answer  updated .. whit and explanation   .. hope is clear